# EventType.MouseDown with middle mouse button strange behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This behavior is not clear to me.
In a MonoBehaviour I have this code:

```
void OnGUI() {
   Event e = Event.current;
   Vector3 mousePosition = e.mousePosition;
   mousePosition.y = Screen.height - mousePosition.y;
   Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
   RaycastHit hitInfo;
   if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo)) {
      if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseDown && e.button == 0) {
          Debug.Log("DOWN 0");
       } else if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseDown && e.button == 1) {
          Debug.Log("DOWN 1");
       } else if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseDown && e.button == 2) {
          Debug.Log("DOWN 2");
       } else if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseUp && e.button == 0) {
          Debug.Log("UP 0");
       } else if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseUp && e.button == 1) {
          Debug.Log("UP 1");
       } else if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseUp && e.button == 2) {
          Debug.Log("UP 2");
       }
   }
}
```

All cases work except

```
if (e.rawType == EventType.MouseDown && e.button == 2) {
      Debug.Log("DOWN 2");
}
```

Is there a reason why the mouse down of the middle mouse button is not intercepted?

Comment: Strange .. in general I would recommend to use only one `if(e.rawType == EventType.MouseDown)` and wrap the `e.button` inside it with a `switch-case` .. the same for the `EventType.MouseUp` this would reduce some redundant checks.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I have optimized the code as you suggested. But the issue is not solved. I tried to move the line to the first position (absurd) then I changed the mouse. Since I'm using Unity 2019 I tried the code in 2018. No difference. If I use this code (slightly modified) in the OnSceneGui of the editor or in Update of the Monobehaviour by modifying it in Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2) in Play Mode it works. For now I will move the code to EventType.MouseUp but if someone finds time to do a verification of this we could possibly report it as a issue.

Comment: Note that I tested your script and it works without problems: https://imgur.com/Z9fZwGD

Comment: It's a mistery. I created a new scene cleaned of all my code, only a cube and its attached script like in your demo. Nothing changes. Can you tell me which version of Unity you are working with? I must be able to understand why, if it happens to me it can also happen to those who could use my editor.

Comment: I used Unity 2019.1.0b9